# How can I call my API of Shipping when the order is placed using my custom shipping module?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, shipping-methods

I have created a custom shipping method and is appearing in the admin config page, and also is able in the customer order to be selected. Now I need to do an api call to my shipping company when the order is placed and my custom shipping method is selected.
(To add the custom shipping method I have fallowed this tutorial):

> https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/

Comment: which Shipping Carrier You are using for which you need to call API ?

Comment: Hi @Pawan. Is a custom shipping carrier, I mean is not a big or famous, so I need to notify them.  
In any case, what I need is be able to observe the placed order event and know where and how put code there.